# C# Linq to json how to extract a properties that contain a certains values

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have JSON file in which I would like to extract a certain value of a field name message in C#. So far I code a c# console app, but the LINQ to JSON code would not apply WHERE condition.

```
  using (StreamReader lire = File.OpenText(@"filepath"))
        {
            JObject o = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(lire));


            var liste = from x in o["messages"]
                        where x["message"].Contains("photo")
                        select x["message"];
            foreach (var x in liste)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Here a sample a JSON FILE

```
  {
  "message": "[Debug][CollectCtrl] Location Saved",
  "type": "debug",
  "date": 1488152282281
},
{
  "message": "[Debug]INSERT INTO photo (location_id, lat, lng, json, filename, heading) VALUES (15,0, 0,'{}', 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20170226_163727.jpg',0)",
  "type": "debug",
  "date": 1488152282285
},
{
  "message": "[Debug]INSERT INTO photo (location_id, lat, lng, json, filename, heading) VALUES (15,0, 0,'{}', 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20170226_163718.jpg',0)",
  "type": "debug",
  "date": 1488152282289
},
{
  "message": "[Debug]Photo saved.28",
  "type": "debug",
  "date": 1488152282439
},
```

Comment: When I tried to validate your sample JSON file, I got an error saying JSON is not properly formatted.

Comment: the sample the I post is inside of array named messages:

Comment: Notice the change in my code from `JObject` to `JArray`. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: after an hour of fixing the bug, I have just created a string variable containing the value, while looping and I add a if condition:
   foreach(var x in liste)
                {
                    string valeur = x.ToString();

                    if(valeur.Contains("[Debug]INSERT INTO photo"))
                    {do stuff }

Comment: If it is resolved then great! Please mark the answer as correct one if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code.

```
 using (var sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\sranade\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AccessModifiers\AccessModifiers\sample.json"))
        {
            var o = (JArray)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(sr));
            foreach (var obj in o.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (var p in obj.Properties())
                {
                    if (p.Name.Contains("message") && p.Value.ToString().Contains("photo"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(p.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

An below code is using LINQ to JSON

```
  var messageList = o.Select(x => x["message"]).Where(x => x.ToString().Contains("photo")).ToList();
            foreach (var message in messageList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
```